# Why am I not getting the right answer for this limit problem?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, radicals, infinity

**The problem:**

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGH7V.jpg)

"Let

f(x) = 3x + sqrt(9x^2 + 2x + 1)

Calculate

a) lim(x→∞) = f(x)

b) lim(x→-∞) = f(x)."

**My calculations / what I have tried:**

[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2PQo.jpg)

[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoa7C.jpg)

[part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Dsa.jpg)

[part 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NPLn.jpg)

**The answer key to this problem:**

[answer key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br42D.jpg)

"a) DNE! [“∞ + ∞”]

b) -1/3 (expand with the conjugate)"

**How my math book solves a similar problem:**

[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMFQ4.jpg)

[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d435e.jpg)

**My questions to you:**

- What am I doing wrong? Why won’t I get the right answers? Have I made an error along the way?
- Why is [“∞ + ∞”] only of relevance in question a)? How do I come to the conclusion “∞ + ∞” for a)?
- And ultimately, how would you solve this problem?

Please, help me understand. I have read pdfs and watched multiple videos on these specific type of problems and they all seem to have employed a similar method to mine but my calculations won’t lead me to the right answer it seems. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the limit on an algebraic expression $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)$ is not defined for $f(x_0)$, it is customary to find another expression $g(x)=f(x)$ on wich the limit has a defined value. Because of this, several procedures lead to different limits. The key is to search for the ones that give you a reasonable answer.
In your exercise, you’ll have a better luck if you do not use the absolute value function $|\cdot|$. To see this, check these calculations:
$$3x+\sqrt{9x^2+2x+1}=\frac{-(2x+1)}{3x-\sqrt{9x^2+2x+1}}$$
On the limit, we get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow - \infty} \frac{-(2x+1)}{3x-\sqrt{9x^2+2x+1}} = \frac{-(2(-\infty)+1)}{3(-\infty)-\sqrt{9(-\infty)^2+2(-\infty)+1}} = \frac{2\infty}{-3\infty-\sqrt{9\infty^2}} = \frac{2\infty}{-3\infty-3\infty} = \frac{2\infty}{-6\infty}=-\frac{1}{3}$$